Quasar BEX App port connection is Disconnected after a short time
When using Quasar BEX (Browser Extension) the connection with the App is lost and shown as disconnected (in allActiveConnections)
How to keep the service worker/background page running or how to reconnect it? Seems like after certain amount of inactivity the service worker is terminated, and content page is unable to send message due to disconnected = true in client-entry.js :
  function connect () {
    ...
    port.onDisconnect.addListener(() => {
      disconnected = true;
    });
    ...
  });

